# Errror on connecting to VPN-server by Demand-dial interface (Windows Server 2008 R2)

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, nat

I have several LAN-interfaces and internet access over VPN (connect to provider VPN-server). I want to setup NAT from local area networks to internet. For this I install on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard feature "Routing and Remote Access" and create Demand-dial interface to VPN-server. But I can't connect to this interface. And in event viewer I have next error message:

```
CoId={10CA7799-B54D-41F8-B8A8-7F92CF662137}: The user SYSTEM dialed a connection named Global world which has failed. The error code returned on failure is 720.
```

And before this, information message with configuration of connection:

```
CoId={10CA7799-B54D-41F8-B8A8-7F92CF662137}: The user SYSTEM has started dialing a VPN connection using a all-user connection profile named Global world. The connection settings are: 
Dial-in User = 00332
VpnStrategy = PPTP then L2TP
DataEncryption = None
PrerequisiteEntry = 
AutoLogon = No
UseRasCredentials = Yes
Authentication Type = PAP/CHAP/MS-CHAPv2 
Ipv4DefaultGateway = Yes
Ipv4AddressAssignment = By Server
Ipv4DNSServerAssignment = By Server
Ipv6DefaultGateway = Yes
Ipv6AddressAssignment = By Server
Ipv6DNSServerAssignment = By Server
IpDnsFlags = 
IpNBTEnabled = No
UseFlags = Private Connection
ConnectOnWinlogon = No
IPsec authentication for L2TP = Machine certificate.
```

But if I try to connect to an ISP by connection created in "Network and Sharing Center", then everything works. And in event viewer I have next message:

```
CoId={0BC9B4DF-10DB-4239-9FB7-3F819B9DB575}: The user SPBANGEL-HOME\Administrator has started dialing a VPN connection using a per-user connection profile named VPN Connection. The connection settings are:
Dial-in User = 00332
VpnStrategy = IKEv2 , SSTP , PPTP then L2TP
DataEncryption = None
PrerequisiteEntry = 
AutoLogon = No
UseRasCredentials = Yes
Authentication Type = PAP/CHAP/MS-CHAPv2 
Ipv4DefaultGateway = Yes
Ipv4AddressAssignment = By Server
Ipv4DNSServerAssignment = By Server
Ipv6DefaultGateway = Yes
Ipv6AddressAssignment = By Server
Ipv6DNSServerAssignment = By Server
IpDnsFlags = Register primary domain suffix
IpNBTEnabled = Yes
UseFlags = Private Connection
ConnectOnWinlogon = No
IPsec authentication for L2TP = Machine certificate
Mobility enabled for IKEv2 = Yes.
```

As I see, there are some differences in configurations. What means parameters *VpnStrategy*, *IpDnsFlags*, *IpNBTEnabled* and *Mobility enabled for IKEv2*? And where I can change values for this parameters? Or my problem is not it?

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Sorry, no. I can't found solution.

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Though I use more specific settings (only PPTP, only MS-CHAPv2 etc) (tried default settings too).